# HTML Number Field Checking

Tags: php, html

In HTML number field I want that a user enters numbers between 10 to 20 and then 40 to 50... How to implement this inside an HTML text field or a number field.

Comment: is it going to be continued? is these restriction defined in the server?

Comment: Can't you use JavaScript to check it?

Comment: Will it be two separate number fields?

Comment: Check my answer it's what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in HTML 5 you can do this

```html
<form action="">
<input type="number" min="10" max="20"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

If you are getting value from database/ want to integrate with php values, you can do something like following.

```
<input type="number" min="<?php echo $minVal ?>" max="<?php echo $maxVal ?>"/>
```

REMEMBER: when you are doing validation you has to do the validation for front end end back end. And min and max attribute are not only limited to `number` type, you can use it for `date` type also refer **[this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_max_min)**

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to use javascript or jquery you can use **min** and **max** attributes

```
<input type="number" min="10" max="20">
<input type="number" min="40" max="50">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't suppose it is possible using html alone. You will have to use JavaScript validation because the condition here is complex with regard to html.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with patter in html5 :

```
<input type="text" name="range" pattern="^(?:\d[10-20]|\d[40-50])$" >
```

Check it simple and short using javascript :

```js
function allownums(a) 
{ 
value1 = a.value;
if( (10<value1==value1<20) || (40<value1==value1<50)) 
alert("vaild") 
else 
alert("invaild") 
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='numonly' onkeyup='allownums(this)'>
```

if you want to using html only you can use two number field:

```
<input type="number" min="10" max="20">
<input type="number" min="40" max="50">
```